# Why AW API post call return internal server error?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
 data = json.loads(json.dumps(event))
 #payload = data['data'] #---------------------->1
 payload = "9,3,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1". #--------->2
 response = runtime.invoke_endpoint(EndpointName=ENDPOINT_NAME,ContentType='text/csv',Body=payload)
 result = json.loads(response['Body'].read().decode())

return {
    'statusCode': 200,
    'headers': { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    'body': json.dumps({"isApproved": result})
};
```

When I invoke this Lamda function via AWS API gateway as it is, I am able to get what I want wehn I make a post request.

However, when I uncomment line --->1 and comment --->2, I get {"message":"Internal Server Error"} for the same post request. Please note **when I run either way in lambda itself, both work fine and return exactly the same result**. The issue will pop up when we make an API post call. Please let me know if you have any idea.

Comment: Enable Cloudwatch execution INFO logs on the API stage with full request/response and check what the specific error message is.

Answer (score 0):

AWS API Gateway stringify the HTTP request body in the Event's `body` property.

To get the request body (payload) from event, you will need to get it from 'body' property.

`payload = json.loads(event['body'])`

Comment: Thanks, Khan, for coming back on this. I am sorry if I had not asked the question properly. However, I am not able to find your answer relevant. Could you please check the question again?

Comment: Hi Khan, please ignore my reply above. It worked. However, Lambda itself still returns error while API gateway return the right response. Put a detailed comment below.

Answer (score 0):

Sorted out the issue as suggested by Khan above: The code should be as below.

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
print("Received event: " + json.dumps(event, indent=2))
data = json.loads(event['body'])
payload = data['data']
response = runtime.invoke_endpoint(EndpointName=ENDPOINT_NAME,ContentType='text/csv',Body=payload)
result = json.loads(response['Body'].read().decode())

return {
    'statusCode': 200,
    'headers': { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    'body': json.dumps({"isApproved": result})
};
```

However, if you run this in Lambda, it will return the follwing error.

```
"errorType": "KeyError",
```

Nevertheless, API gateway would render it very fine.

Comment: You sorted out the issue using the exact same line I suggested you in my answer i.e. `json.loads(event['body'])` and yet you commented in my answer that it is irrelevant to your question. Anyway, I am glad it is sorted.

Comment: Apologize; I forgot to reply you. When I was trying first in the way you suggested, Lamda was returning error. Since the error was returned when I enabled the line #payload = data['data'] in my original code, I focus was on that particular line; that is why I replied it was not relevant. However, while Lambda was till returning error, I just tried with API gateway after spending some more time, interestingly it was working via API gateway but not in Lambda. I totally forgot you had suggested the same earlier. Going to acknowledge that though.  Thanks for your help.